# Least verbose way of defining a default array value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, conventions, ternary-operator

Is there a cleaner way to check for array values to prevent PHP notices? Currently I do this:

```
$email      = (isset($_POST['user_email']))      ? $_POST['user_email']      : '';
$first_name = (isset($_POST['user_first_name'])) ? $_POST['user_first_name'] : '';
$last_name  = (isset($_POST['user_last_name']))  ? $_POST['user_last_namel'] : '';
$birthday   = (isset($_POST['user_last_name']))  ? $_POST['user_last_namel'] : '';
```

Is there a way to do something like JavaScript where you just provide a default, like this?

```
user.email = response.email || '';
```

I don't want to suppress notices, but these ugly checks clutter up my code. I'm on **PHP 5.2.6**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function:

```
$email      = getPost('user_email');
$first_name = getPost('user_first_name');
$last_name  = getPost('user_last_name');
$birthday   = getPost('user_birthday');


function getPost($key, $default = '')
{
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
        return $_POST[$key];
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Putting it in a function also let's you do additional sanitizing more easily, e.g., `trim()`, if desired.

You can also pass a default value that will be returned:

```
$flavor = getPost('flavor', 'vanilla'); // if $_POST['flavor'] is not set, 'vanilla' is returned
```

Comment: IMHO the least reasonable way of doing this, logic-wise. You repeatedly spread the default everywhere in code, making it hard to change and track errors down when you forgot to change it at a single point. Defaults should be stored in a central location, like an array containing defaults and declared as such. (see `array_merge` or `array_intersect_keys` approach) DRY, Dont Repeat Yourself.

Comment: No one says you have to use literals for the defaults. You can still have a centralized location for that info: `$flavor = getPost('flavor', Settings::get('default_flavor'));`

Comment: @Kaii, all of this is wrong of course. You should have dependency injection and automatic input validation. _How_ that is achieved is not important. But for this environment this solution would have my preference. Yours could be useful if you have many many input arguments, but that's extraordinary in itself.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen i don't see where the Dependency Injection Pattern somehow applies to this, please elaborate. mario's intersect approach includes `array_filter()` which is very handy for validation if applied correctly. Also, i don't see any sense in the numerous function calls which i consider just overhead, when you can easily access a centrally generated, filtered array to retrieve your values. I don't wanna argue, just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a set of attributes, then one concise option is [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge). Note that the defaults go first:

```
 $post = array_merge(
      array("email" => "", "first_name" => "", "last_name" => "", "birthday" => ""),
      $_POST
 );
```

Then just access them as is:

```
 $email = $post["email"];   // it's assured there is some value
```

An even more compact way to localize a limited set of variables is [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) in combination with [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key). But only in that combination - to prevent importing arbitrary variables:

```
 extract(array_merge($defaults, array_intersect_key(array_filter($_POST), $defaults)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen at least three ways of doing this.

### Adding array with defaults

```
$options = $_POST + $defaults;
```

where `$options` is an associative array having everything `$_POST` had, but with added keys and values from `$defaults` (unless there was a value in `$_POST` for specific key in `$defaults`, then this specific key/value pair from `$defaults` is ignored and value for this specific key in `$_POST` is not replaced).

### Merging with array of defaults

As shown by @mario (use `array_merge()`):

```
$options = array_merge($defaults, $_POST);
```

### Using helper functions...

...such as Kohana's [`Arr::get()` helper](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/arr.php#L275):

```
/* ... */
public static function get($array, $key, $default = NULL)
{
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
/* ... */
```

which has some advantage of easily replacing default value (which, by default is `NULL`). It can be used like that:

```
echo Arr::get($_POST, 'user_email');
```

or:

```
echo Arr::get($_POST, 'user_email', 'N/A');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function assure(&$a, $default=null) {
  if (!isset($a)) $a=$default;
  return $a;
}

$email=assure($_POST['user_email'],'');
$first_name=assure($_POST['user_first_name'],'');
```

Comment: This will throw **warnings** if `$_POST['user_email']` etc. are not set

Comment: Are you sure about that? I use it all the time without warnings. In the call I only give a reference, which doesn't trigger a warning, and inside isset() there is also no warning.

Comment: Using a reference actually **creates** `$_POST['user_email']` if it doesn't exist. That's why you don't get the warning. It's not good practice to create new elements in the `$_POST` array just to avoid warnings.

Comment: @webbiedave no it doesn't. I couldn't believe what you said but was unsure if my assumption is wrong. i created a simple test case here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/3Kpi2U

Comment: You might not get warnings if your default error level is set too low. As a rule of thumb: in development use the _lowest_ error level available; that is: `E_ALL`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php Also, I don't know who upvoted webbiedave's comment, but it's **incorrect**. A reference does not get a value until you assign it a value. Simply referencing it will not give it a value (that would be weird).

Comment: @webbiedave: +1 You are totally correct (http://ideone.com/gLusn). Also I agree with that `$_POST` should not be modified by such code.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I upvoted webbiedave's comment and here is a proof that **he _is_ correct**: http://ideone.com/gLusn

Comment: I'm sorry Tadeck, you are incorrect and your example does not prove that you are. The `string(0) ""` is result of the `assure` function. If you `var_dump($a['user_first_name'])` directly you will get `null`. As you can see here: http://ideone.com/nlrxC

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Yes, it is a result of the `assure` function, because it assigns instead of simply returning. Here is the result of `var_dump($a['user_first_name'])` after invoking `assure()`: http://ideone.com/ibNdn. I believe it was what webbiedave had in mind.

Comment: That may be, but it still throws a **WARNING**, which is bad practice.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I stated that it *creates* the variable. I never said it was assigned a value (it's null). How's this (key doesn't exist before function call, exists after): http://codepad.viper-7.com/YPCTEi

Comment: Fair enough, but the value is still `null`. And again, this _will_ throw a warning.

Comment: i'm impressed. applies to references to non-existent array keys only. my example (also in comments) is proof that it does not apply to simple variable references.

Comment: @Kaii: It applies to simple variables as well (remember, `isset` only returns true if a variable exists **and** is not set to `null`): http://codepad.viper-7.com/7LKOxf

Comment: Pretty sure an undefined index is a notice, not a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DefaultArray](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#defaultarray) from [NSPL](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl):

```
$post = defaultarray('', $_POST);

$email = $post['user_email'];
$first_name = $post['user_first_name'];
$last_name = $post['user_last_name'];
$birthday = $post['user_birthday'];
```